# Add facebook og:image meta tag dynamically using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, meta-tags

need a small help
I am using a facebook share button for my website. But when I share the post/article page, Facebook shows on the part of my logo, instead of the respective Image of the article

I have added the following code in meta tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image;?>"/>
```

However when I use the facebook share debugger, it says the image is not found.
An once its shared on facebook. I searched a lot, but was unable to resolve.

Comment: how do you get $image?

Comment: $image  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'large' );

Comment: you have to put the full url of the image., whats the value of **$image**

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image_src` returns an _array_, the URL is in the first element in that, so get it from there. (Or use `wp_get_attachment_image_url` to begin with - that is a wrapper function that calls `wp_get_attachment_image_src` and returns the first element of the result.)

Answer (score 0):

Use "WP Social Sharing" plugin for WordPress to share post page on social media.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-social-sharing/